# How to display numbers in the math mode in the same font as in the text?

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I have set my default font family for the text as sans serif with `\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`  and now I want for the math mode to display the numbers in the same way as they appear outside of it. 
I have tried a couple of solutions such as using `\DeclareMathVersion` declaration followed by `\SetSymbolFont` and `\SetMathAlphabet`  as well as `\textrm`  command from amsmatch package but the font still turns out different from when just writing out numerical characters outside the math mode.

Comment: Please tell us which TeX distribution, which TeX format -- pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or possibly something entirely else -- and which fonts you use.

Comment: Glad you found another posting that provides a solution that works for you. I would like to suggest that this posting be "closed" as a result.

Comment: Package `mathastext` is an alternative to `sansmath`, the latter only dealing with obtaining sans-serif in math mode, whereas `mathastext` allows to use arbitrary fonts.